# Do editors of other journals get asked to review papers?

Tags: journals, peer-review, editors

If editor of Journal A finds that the speciality of the editor of journal B is very close to the subject of a paper submitted to Journal A. Would the editor of journal A ask the editor of journal B to review the paper?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 8):

Probably not in their capacity as editor of journal B, but certainly probable in their capacity as known expert in the field (and if the fields are near, they'll probably have professional connections anyway).

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely.  I am a journal editor, and I am also frequently asked to act as a reviewer for other journals on related manuscripts (and also often accept these requests).

At the journal where I am an editor, however, it is considered inappropriate to ask for reviews from *other editors of the same journal*.  This is because they are assumed to already be working hard enough for that particular community by acting as editors, and the journal leadership wants to make sure the work gets spread more widely.